# Why did I stop getting achievements halfway through Portal 2?

Tags: achievements, portal-2

I played through Portal 2's single player in 4 hours yesterday, however, I have only gained achievements for the first hour or so of playtime.

What could have caused this? I didn't use any cheats, the developer console was disabled, and I haven't found any information on anything else that could cause achievements to not be awarded.

Comment: Did you have Steam in online mode all the time?

Comment: I didn't turn it off online mode, but its entirely possible my connection dropped out a few times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had this happen to me. I would guess your internet connection gave out or you were not logged in to steam. IF you're lucky the achievements were saved locally and will upload once you login to steam. But chances are you just need to get them again.

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused by your Internet connection dropping out or someone else logging into your Steam account.  Either way your session has been disconnected from Steam.

It is a good idea to have the console open because it tells you when achievements are not being earned if it's a different server.dll or you are disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you didn't have sv_cheats set to 1. That enables cheat mode, which disables achievements. It could also be an issue with Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Check the event log of your OS to see if there are any messages related to your connection.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: And how is this a comment? Dropping connections is the answer to this question.

Comment: There's no mention of achievement recording being related to connection issues; it sounds like a 'look at X and see if there are issues' which may be a comment to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: @Alok: How else would you figure out the actual problem? I can't look into the event log for the user, can I? Why do I explicitly have to mention that I'm responding to `Why did I stop getting achievements halfway through Portal 2?`? This makes no sense.

Comment: 'You could have gone offline which caused achievements to not register' would have answered the question, this made no mention of any probable cause - though it is clear when considering other answers & comments on the question itself. Maybe the online requirement is so obvious everyone knows it and I'm missing something.

Comment: That probable cause would be listed in the event log, that's how Windows works.